# One to many mapping in nhibernate but can't save father's ID in the data table for child entity

Tags: nhibernate

If anyone can help me? why the value of the field fatherid is null after executing the test codes?
1) father entity definition:

```
class father
{
   public virtual string name;
   public virtual string id;
   public virtual IList<child> children;
}
```

2) child entity definition:

```
class child
{
   public virtual string id;
   public virtual string name;
}
```

3) mapping file for father

```
<class name ="father" table="dbfather">
<id name="id" column ="id">
  <generator class ="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name ="name"/>
<bag name="ichild">
<key column="fatherid" />
<one-to-many class="child" />
</bag>
</class>
```

4) mapping file for child

```
<class name ="child" table="dbchild">
<id name="id" column ="id">
  <generator class ="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name ="name"/>
</class>
```

5) test codes

```
var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory())
        {
            ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            try
            {
                Child c = new Child();
                c.id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                c.name= "test"; 
                Father f = new Father();
                f.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                f.name= "ftest";
                f.children.Add(child); 

                session.Save(c);
                session.Save(f);
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public virtual IList<string> children;
```

should be

```
public virtual IList<Child> children;
```

Comment: yes, you are right, that's my mistake, thanks for your reminding me

Comment: let me guess, it was not the actual problem. But since the code won't even run with the compiler errors and obvious typos (ichild => children) it's hard to tell where the problem in the real code is.